# Dart / Flutter - cannot assign bool value from JSON response

Tags: json, dart, flutter, boolean

Newbie to Dart/Flutter here struggling with problem while assigning bool valuse from JSON response - `bool error` is `null` and I'm getting:

**Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null**

I don't know what's going on as the response is decoded properly and there's no problem with other fields (please take look at Logcat output).

this is my JSON:

```
{
"error:":false,
"id":1,
"name":"test"
}
```

my Future:

```
Future<dynamic> fetchData() async {
http.Response response = await http.get(Values.URL, headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"});

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  debugPrint(response.body);

  var body = jsonDecode(response.body);

  bool error = body["error"];
  var id = body["id"];
  var name = body["name"];

  print("bool:" + error.toString());
  print("id:" + id.toString());
  print("name:" + name);

  if (error) {
    print("no error");
  } else {
    print("error");
  }
} else {
  throw Exception("statusCode exception e");
}
```

and the Logcat output:

```
I/flutter: {
I/flutter:   "error:":false,
I/flutter:   "id":1,
I/flutter:   "name":"test"
I/flutter: }
I/flutter: bool:null
I/flutter: id:1
I/flutter: name:test
I/flutter: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?
Any help will be much appreciated! THANK YOU :)

Comment: Try `bool error = body["error:"];` or is the `:` in `"error:":false,` a mistake in the question?

Comment: Already tried that - I'm still getting null value...

Comment: Then set a breakpoint at `bool error = body["error"];` and investigate `body`

Comment: Oh my my my .... looks like I need a coffe break after spending 7 hours with code :)
The problem was a colon im json code....
THANK YOU, Gunter for pointing this out :)

Comment: @Matt, please post answers as answer not as a comment, and then accept it (yes you can accept your own answer and this is encouraged) so that question doesn't hang as unanswered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd like to thank Günter Zöchbauer for pointing out my silly mistake in JSON structure:

```
"error:":false
```

should be:

```
"error":false
```

don't forget to take a break from coding guys... ;)